# Changing filedpot user interface

Tags: 7, files

Do anyone know how to remove the 'Please Wait' pop up from the filedepot interface? I've searched through the files and can't find it

[image: Please wait screenshot]

from Filedepot?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Removing feedback user gets is usually bad idea, "please wait" overlay is there for a reason. Precisely, to prevent user from clicking other things while this action is still processing, and do let user know site is working, not crashed.

Comment: My manager hates it and wants it gone!

Comment: you should explain UX and UI to your manager... presumably it's an ajax call, which means if you try to do something else while it is running you could break something, or at least cause an error to show. Personally I'd rather a please wait, over an ajax 200 error being presented to an impatient user